# Create zip file with dynamic address and dynamic file and get zip file link

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put 2 files, one is **thanks.txt** and the other is **file.dat**, into a zip file with the following codes, and then link to this zip file, but my code does not run correctly and I need help to correct and optimized this code.

Inside the **thanks.txt** file, the following text is placed with the customer's user email:

`Hi, Dear '.$email_address.' Thanks for using it!`

**My codes:**

```
funtion create_zip_file() {
    
    // Get Current User Email Address!
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $email_address = $current_user->user_email;
    
    $md5_address = md5($email_address);

    $directory_path = 'myfiles/cloud/' . $md5_address . '/';
    if (!file_exists($directory_path)) {
        mkdir($directory_path, 0777, true);
    }
    
    $Myfile = file_put_contents($directory_path . 'file.dat' , $email_address);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
        $website_url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/';
    } else {
        $website_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/';
    }

    $result = $website_url . $directory_path . 'file.dat'; 

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($zip_file , ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        // Add files to the zip file
        $zip->addFile($result);
        
        // Add a file new.txt file to zip using the text specified
        $zip->addFromString('thanks.txt', 'Hi, Dear '.$email_address.' Thanks for use it!');
     
        // All files are added, so close the zip file
        $zip->close();
        
        // Delete file after zip it
        unlink($result);
    }
    
    $zip_file = $website_url . $directory_path . 'file.zip';
    
    if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
        return $zip_file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And I call the zip file by the following line:**

`<a href="<?php echo create_zip_file();"> Download zip file </a>`

If I use static address in the following line(**$zip_file**):

`if ($zip->open($zip_file , ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)`

The zip file is created, but when I use the dynamic address, no zip file is created

Comment: _"but when I use the dynamic address, no zip file is created"_ - so what "dynamic address" are you imagining you're actually using then ...? `if ($zip->open($zip_file , ...` - there isn't even a `$zip_file` variable in the function context at this point, the first time you assign a value to that is _after_ this if block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$zip->addFile($result);` expects valid *path on server*, but you pass in *URL to that file* instead.

Same with `$zip_file = $website_url . $directory_path . 'file.zip';`

---

Use same path that you use to to create `.dat` file: `$zip->addFile($directory_path . 'file.dat')`

Comment: When I use this code ($zip->addFile($directory_path . 'file.dat')), the directory is included in the zip file, that is (myfiles/cloud/md5 email/file.dat)
I don't want the path (myfiles, cloud and md5email folders) to be saved either.

What should I do for addressing? When I use ($website_url . $directory_path . 'file.zip') it doesn't find a file, but if I use ($directory_path . 'file.zip') it finds the file! Where is the problem? Is the website_url wrong?

Comment: @SubZer0 You are mixing URL with path: basically your zip archive looks for path on server to be e.g. `C://https://example.com/myfiles/cloud/ABC123/file.zip`

Comment: To change path: use second argument in `addFile($result, '/path/in/zip/archive/file.dat')` [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php)

Comment: Thank you, it was great, my problem was solved with this code `$zip->addFile($directory_path . 'file.dat' , 'file.dat');`

Comment: Is it possible to put a password and comment on the generated zip file?

Comment: @SubZer0 Please read documentation/google it for ZipArchive: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254778/discussion-between-justinas-and-subzer0).

Comment: @SubZer0 , you can use this line to set password for each file: `$zip->setEncryptionName('FILENAME_WITH_EXTENSION', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, 'PASSWORD'); //Add file name and password dynamically`

Comment: @SubZer0 , and for comment use it: `$zip->setArchiveComment('Sample Comments!');`